# Handling missing dotnet core framework 1.0.5 on nanoserver on docker

Tags: docker, nano-server

I have a little dotnet core app which I use. 
I've been running it on my virtualbox-based docker on my development PCs by pulling it from GIT and restoring and running it from a bash shell.

Now I am using a Windows Server with Docker EE installed - I've got a container built from the microsoft/dotnet image (based on Windows Nanoserver) but while it restores ok, when trying to run I get an error.

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.5' was
>   not found.

How can I install a version of framework from the command line or powershell in this nanoserver installation?
Or should I be looking at another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest answer was to just use a version of the docker image with the appropriate version of dotnet core installed: microsoft/dotnet:1.0.5-sdk-nanoserver

For installations in an existing container the dockerfile might provide some clue: 
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/1.0/sdk/nanoserver/Dockerfile